# Activating mouse event in visual object in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am creating my own control from derived from drawingvisual class and drawn a rectangle. I want to enable mouse events for this object. how can I achieve this?
I thing implementing IInputElement interface might be the solution. Could you guys suggest me how to implement this interface.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The DrawingVisual class doesn't offer any mouse events, and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.aspx) the `IInputElement` interface is "not intended to be implemented in application or framework-building scenarios."

Maybe you would be better deriving from `UserControl` and using DrawingVisual to provide visual content for it?